# tiny changes of properties file doesn't take effective after an "ant all" build

Tags: ant

I'm new to Java and currently involve in a project, this problem confuses me a lot. When I updated my properties files and run "ant all", normally it works when I check it on webpage.

But it didn't work every time, for example, if there is just a tiny change: like from word "Cookiex" => "Cookies"

```
AccountLogin.cookiesJavaScript=(Cookiex and JavaScript must be enabled)
```

=>

```
AccountLogin.cookiesJavaScript=(Cookies and JavaScript must be enabled)
```

After I do the change, and run "ant all", I couldn't find the change takes effective on webpage.

Incidentally, I found if I tried to make some more changes (even just adding one blank at the end of line) :

```
AccountLogin.cookiesJavaScript=(Cookies and JavaScript must be enabled)
```

then run "ant all", the change takes effective! - it seems the first "ant all" ignored my **tiny changes**?

I don't know the root cause of this problem and hope someone can explain it for me and help to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: Before being able to answer, it looks like your ant script is executing an ant task that generates your webpage.  Perhaps your webpage is not being generated if it doesn't detect any changes.  And furthermore, perhaps looking for changes is case insensitive and hence some changes are not found, when you would expect them to be.

Comment: Hi, Andrew: thanks for replying! My example might not be very good, it's not just "case insensitive" problem (like from "s" to "S"), I'll update the post to avoid confusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem is:

I use Bitvise SFTP of Bitvise Tunnelier 4.32 to update file, it didn't really update server file at that time! When I change to use filezilla, this problem is gone.